# How to post website url with its contents in android app same like post website url functionality of google plus android app

Tags: android, google-plus

We are trying to post url in our android app using jsoup library. We want to implement post website url functionality same as in **Google Plus** android app. But, the problem is, we are not able to fetch image from url which google plus android app fetching specific images from website url while posting.

We are getting image url from website html source in meta,link tags but each website html source contains image in any tag. How can we get the specific image url from any website url which is implemented by google plus android app.

Please, Check following image.. We want to implement same as like when user enters website url after that it's title, description and image need to displays on screen...
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJWUA.jpg

Comment: be more clear while asking question, better provide some assistance to your question in form of links or code

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add preview of "some imgs of posting URL". Google plus downloads imgs to their servers then shows them to users as preview of web urls(if you right click G+(web site) post img and open in new tab, you will see the image address as google... application must have the same ).

If you want to do it dynamically, you may almost fail because of parsing imgs all the time while showing url post.

You should parse imgs of urls only once, make the user select one of them to preview then save img into your databse. While showing preview of URLS, stream imgs from your database.

if you can parse the image url and use it dynamically than,

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.org/someimage.jpg");
Bitmap bmp =        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

if you can not parse the img url, you can show a message as "We could not find any img to preview!" or hide imageView of preview img.

Comment: No @sedpol. We want to implement it dynamically.. Means, when user enters the website url.. title,description and image of website will displays to the user.. Can you plz check out the google plus android app and its link post feature then you will understand what we want..

Comment: Google+, firstly parses the web link url images(finds the main images via parsing and shows the one of them, facebook does the same), then shows the image as what I did on my answer. The key action is "parsing images from web link url". Could you do parsing process?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.... We have done the parsing process.. & getting the images.. As you said, Google+ shows one of images via parsing.. but, how to rectify which is the main image & its tag like google+ select only one image out of them?

Comment: I do not realy know the algorithm, but g+ selects main image. Also try facebook(web site, I am not sure about mobile application) link post, it makes you select main image from some parsed images via <>(left-right button).